# Need permission for stored proc on database A to select from table on database B

Tags: security, sql-server-2008

I have two databases on the same SQL2008 server, and many stored procedures on one database (call it A) need to access the tables on the other database (B). I made sure the SQL user on A had permission to EXEC the procedure on A, but I also ran `DENY ALL ON mytablename` to attempt a touch of security. I am being dumb somewhere though...

I get this error when running myproc on A:
*Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e09'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'mytablename', database 'B', schema 'dbo'.*

Whilst I could `GRANT SELECT` access to the tables in question this isn't really the solution, is it?! I'd like the procs on either database to have SELECT access to the tables, without the user being able to SELECT from the tables directly.

**Database A has:**
Table - mytablename
User - myuserA (member of db_datareader, linked to a login called 'bob')

**Database B has:**
Proc - myproc (which SELECTs from A..mytablename)
User - myuserB (member of db_datareader, linked to same login 'bob')

I realise we really need a DBA, but we only have two employees!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `DENY ALL ON table`, you are effectively denying permissions regardless if you explicitly grant SELECT. DENY trumps all.

What you want to do is then create views on Database B, and grant SELECT to the users who can run the SP on Database A. Security will propagate from DB A to DB B when the SP on DB A is run.

Comment: Seems like I need to get rid of all the DENY stuff and start again! Is there a way to achieve what I want without using a view?